# How to fire an event when click on a shape file(within a boundary)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, shapefile

Hi I am working on a Xamarin project, and I need to create a floor map with navigation. I have created the map as a shape file and also need to pop the information about meeting rooms when the user slick on the room(location boundary). So how to fire the event when click on it?

How can I do it using Xamarin forms? if not any other way to do it?

Comment: @MichaelRandall since i couldnt find an answer after looking through out the web only have posted here. Thanks

Comment: How far have you got, or are you trying to work out how to do this all?

Comment: I am also looking for same solution, need to fire an event when user click on the Shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var model = GetDataSource();
      ShapeFileLayer layer=new ShapeFileLayer();
      layer.ItemsSource=model;
      SelectedItemButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
       {
        layer.SelectedItems.Add(model[0]);
       };
      RemoveItemButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
       {
        layer.SelectedItems.Remove(model[0]);
       };
```

Comment: The above code appeared on Syncfusion site as well. Here, I am afraid what is the "SelectedItemButton", if I am not mistaken the above button not as part of the Shapefile and it won't fire when the user tap on the Map